# How to list (certain) files in a directory dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, directory, filenames

I am trying to list (let's say) PDF files in a directory (to a GUI). I know I can manage that with in different ways (like below) but I also want the list is to be current and dynamic. For instance, if someone deletes a PDF file from or adds a PDF file to the directory, I want the application to delete or add the file name to the list instantly, without any refresh.

**Do you know any ways to manage that?**

Here is some of my code:

```
import os

pdffiles = [name for name in os.listdir('somedir')
               if name.endswith('.pdf')]

for file in pdffiles:
    print(file)
```

I am in a learning progress.

Comment: Without any refresh? Could you specify that any further. You should continuously or periodically check the size of the directory for example or compare two indexed lists to see If anything was added or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good so far. If you want to do this programmatically (avoiding pynotify or signal handling), the simplest way to maintain a directory listing in your application is via polling the directory.

So, your code might look like:

```
import os
import time

## run indefinitely
while True:
    ## get the directory listing
    pdffiles = [name for name in os.listdir('somedir')
               if name.endswith('.pdf')]

    ## print the most recent listing
    for file in pdffiles:
        print(file)

    ## wait a little bit before getting the next listing
    ## if you want near instantaneous updates, make the sleep value small.
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get notified by the OS that the directory and/or some files changed.

- On Linux you can use [pyinotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify)
- On OSX you can do that with [MACFSEvents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents)
- On Windows (.Net) you can try to interface with FileSystemWatcher, but I am not aware of any specific libraries for that.

And a platform independent solutions is [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)

Hooking that into your program is non-trivial, but the examples of watchdog are clear and that means there is no need for polling.